# Ruby on Rails Syntax for Background Image in HTML.ERB file

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, sass, background-image, erb

I have many articles so I can't put a static URL to background-image under `syle="background-image`.

I tried this in my _article.html.erb file:-

```
<div class="hero_image" style="background-image: url("<%= article.image_url %>")">
```

but it renders out this:

```
<div class="hero_image" style="background-image: url(" uploads="" lines="" article="" hero_image="" 1="" budapest-cropped.jpg")"="">
    </div>
```

so, nevermind, I try this instead under my article.scss.erb file:-

```
  .hero_image {
    background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'article.image_url' %>);
```

but it renders out this:

```
background-image: url(/article.image_url);
```

Totally not what I'm looking for, I need it to render out

`<div class="hero_image" style="background-image: url("/uploads/lines/article/hero_image/1/Budapest_Cropped.jpg">
        </div>` under HTML OR `background-image: url(/uploads/lines/article/hero_image/1/Budapest_Cropped.jpg);` under CSS

Ironically, it knew exactly what to do when my code is `<img src="<%= article.image_url %>" alt="<%= article.title %>" />`, but too bad, i don't want a img src tag, i need a background image tag.

Anyone knows what is wrong with my syntax?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: try with url(asset-path('myimage.png')) in your scss file

Comment: @xploshioOn hey, thanks for your reply. but I don't have a static image, so i need to use <%= article.image_url %> in my syntax.

Comment: you are right sorry, the first one seems correct, try to remove the quotations marks from the first, the ones that are inside url(), something like style="background-image: url(<%= article.image_url %>)"

Comment: @xploshioOn omg it works! can't believe it was just a pair of quotation marks that was stopping me from moving on, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one seems to be correct, just remove the quotation marks that are inside the url(), like this

```
<div class="hero_image" style="background-image: url(<%= article.image_url %>)">
```